# Can two different database framework for single application share the same connection object?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, jdbc, ibatis

I have an application in which a.jar is using jdbc framework and b.jar is using ibatis framework for database connectivity,a database operation on a.jar is taking 10 mins for executing as it is having large rows,so can a data base oparation on b.jar will also take time?

According to my knowledge both will have different connection object,but sometimes i mean very intermittenty this issue in which execution of query on b.jar will result in wait because of large query execution in a.jar resulting in entire jvm hung.

So my question is:are both the frameworks are using the same connection object because of which threads are hanging?Please help me,we are facing these issues in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that they might share a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) (which is safe enough, because each application has its' own instance). If you run a long query from "a" then queries from "b" may well hang until the query from "a" completes, it depends on what the transaction [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) is set to in the database (also, when you share a database - not a connection - what you do from one application can take resources from the other; which is what appears to have happened).

Comment: thanks for your reply,the maximum number of connections are 64 as default in app server,so both we be on different connections and we are doing independent operations on the database for these two jars,and the problem is we will see this issue very rarely like once in a month our threads hung because of this long running query,so we dont figure out what might be the reason and what will be the scenario in which the hung is happening intermittently.

Comment: @pankaj Check the isolation level. You haven't given anywhere near enough information for us to debug this for you.

Comment: Hi elliott,i have conformed from customer that its default,can you please help me.